# adonis test returning message: "superagent: Enable experimental feature http2"

Tags: testing, adonis.js

My testing is passing normally, but i’m receiving the message: “superagent: Enable experimental feature http2”

There’s a way to hide this message?

**My test:**

```
test('realiza um registro de usuário', async ({ client }) => {

      const response = await client
        .post('users')
        .header('Authorization', 'bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjMsImlhdCI6MTU3MjQ0MTA2M30.qN4OMAznOj4blEECSUs-miIMn8DLiAvonrYKxysH7y0')
        .send({
          username: 'usuarioteste',
          permission: 'Administrador',
          status: false,
          user_id: null,
          password: 'usuarioteste'
        })
        .end()

      response.assertStatus(200)
      response.assertJSONSubset({
        username: 'usuarioteste',
        permission: 'Administrador',
        status: false
      })
    })
```

When i run `adonis test` i receive:

```
superagent: Enable experimental feature http2
    ✓ realiza um registro de usuário (447ms)

   PASSED
```

There's a way to hide this superagent: Enable experimental feature http2 warning? Someone can explain me what this is happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error message, it's only an information message. This does not matter how the tests are conducted.

The message appears during the `functional` tests.This must be a dependency used by `@adonisjs/vow`.

To my knowledge, I don't think it's possible to hide it.